# EntityFramework library not recognized

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My entrance to the `EntityFramework` world was not welcome. Here is what I am doing to start using the library.

I clean my `App.config` and clean my solution, add EntityFramework's NuGet package via Manage NuGet Packages and then rebuild my solution. But I still cannot use the library I added in my project:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sometimes a simple restart of Visual Studio will solve the issue

Comment: @rexcfnghk He is using the wrong namespace :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The namespace for `Entity Framework` related classes is not *EntityFramework*, but *System.Data.Entity* and underlying namespaces.

So use 
`using System.Data.Entity` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `using System.Data.Entity;` and not `using EntityFramework;`.